# how to ask CMake to hide compile messages?

Tags: cmake

Recently, while building mysql-connector-c++-1.1.0, I noticed that cmake was only displaying the top level [xx%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/... messages and not displaying the compile messages at all (Warnings, however, were displayed).

I strongly prefer this lower verbosity.

How do I configure my own CMakeLists.txt to behave this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behavior. See [CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable%3aCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE).

Did you turn it on by `make VERBOSE=1` or in your main `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: tyvm!  That was EXACTLY IT:  I had SET( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON ) in my CMakeLists.txt - I was going crazy looking for a fix.  Thx again!